# Jqueryui dialog problem with loading new dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

im using jqueryui dialog but there's a problem upon loading it from other file. example i got

hello.php

```
 <button class="btn"></button>

 <div class="xxx"></div>

 $(".btn").click(function(){

     $.post("hi.php",function(e){
         $(".xxx").html(e);
     });
  });
```

hi.php

```
<div class="mydialog"></div>
$(".mydialog").dialog();
```

the problem is when i click the button twice, the dialog will show twice. it will overlap the other dialog.. can we destroy that dialog before creating a new ui when the button has been clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to check if the same dialog is already open before opening another one.

```
$('button').live('click', function() {
    if (!$(".mydialog").parents(".ui-dialog").is(":visible")) { //checking is done here
        $('<p class="mydialog">test</p>').dialog();
    }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/vm4wQ/3/